# SharePoint cascading drop down on visual web part using client side code

Tags: 2010, javascript, visual-web-part, clients.svc

Hi I am working with cascading drop down in a visual web part. I am able to complete this functionality using c# but I want to implement this functionality using JavaScript jquery basically I want to reduce load on server. Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For client side cascading drop downs, I use SPServices.  If you aren't familiar with it here is a link to the [SPCascadeDropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns).

For this you will have to have your cascading structure defined in lists with lookup fields.  After you set that up it's fairly straight forward.

Here's a couple more resources on how to use SPServices and cascading drop downs:

[Two Level Cascading Drop Down in SharePoint 2013 using SPServices](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using)

[Cascading Drop Down Multiple Levels](http://www.uccorner.com/332/sharepoint/cascading-drop-down-multiple-levels/)

Comment: As I mentioned it is not for designer forms or out of box forms.. I need to implement it for a visual web part.. Ascx page

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following link:

http://jedcurl.blogspot.com/2016/03/add-cascading-drop-downs-to-any-list-or.html

Regards,
Chandani Prajapati